# getting an error when I autostart my py script which contain PyQt Gui

Tags: raspbian, boot, gui, root

I'm trying to automatically start a py script which has pyqt5 Gui when I boot my Raspberrypi. I did `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and made a log.text to know what's happening and I received:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection : Could not connect to display
```

How can I solve it? any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe because the desktop hasn’t started yet. Probably better to use the LXDE autostart file

Comment: +1 For using a log and posting the error.  99%+ of the people who post here about that have not bothered and often have all tried all kinds that didn't work because they were based on incorrect theories about the problem (which is "could not connect to display").

Comment: Does the script starts from the command line? If so, what exactly is the command? Please add it to the question, don't use a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to start foreground applications from `/etc/rc.local`.

> made a log.text to know what's happening

## \O/

You are possibly the *only* person I've seen take this time and confusion saving step here in the context of this very common problem -- we get at least one post a week here about this issue, most of them insisting "my script isn't being run", when of course it is, it just isn't doing what you want.

So fortunately we can skip all that and the error is straightforward, if you understand that the init system (systemd, which runs rc.local), is mostly about starting *background* services, meaning programs which do not need input from the keyboard or a screen to output to.  Which is good, because they don't get one.

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection : Could not connect to display
```

What that literally is about is not being able to connect to a GUI display to open a window.

If you want a GUI application to start at boot, use the *LXDE autostart file*, as another user suggested in comments.  If you search around you will find many examples and discussions of this (there may be some nuances depending exactly what you want to do).

There is also potential confusion regarding the location of the autostart file.  It looks to me from a quick search that for Raspbian/RpiOS buster (the current version), this works:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Not sure if that means it is applied to the `pi` user or if this is global.  If it's the latter it may replace the GUI login.  If not you will have to use autologin for that user (`pi`) to start the program at boot.